# Meteor template: Pass a parameter into each sub template, and retrieve it in the sub-template helper

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I am trying to figure out how to pass a parameter into a sub-template that is in an each block and use the parameter in the sub-template as well as sub-template helper. Here is what I tried so far:

template:

```
<template name="parent">
{{#each nodes }}
{{> child myParam}}
{{/each}}
</template>

<template name="child">
{{ paramName }}
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.parent.nodes = function() { 
//return a list
};
Template.parent.myParam = function() {
return {"paramName" : "paramValue"};
};
Template.child.someOtherHelper = function() {
//How do I get access to the "paramName" parameter?
}
```

So far, it hasn't been working, and it seems somehow mess up my input node list also.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `{{> child myParam}}`, it's calling the child template and associates `myParam` as current template data context, meaning that in the template you can reference `{{paramName}}`.

In `someOtherHelper` you could use `this.paramName` to retrieve `"paramValue"`.
However, when you're using `{{#each nodes}}{{> child}}{{/each}}`, it means that you pass the content of the current list item (fetched from a `LocalCursor` or directly an array item) as the template data of child, and you can reference the list item properties using `{{field}}` in html or `this.field` in js.

What's happening here is when you call `{{> child myParam}}`, the `myParam` helper content OVERWRITES the current node item as template data, that's why it's messing your node list.

A quick (dirty) trick would be to simply extend the `myParam` helper so that it also contains the template data from the `{{#each}}` block.

```
Template.parent.helpers({
  nodes:function(){
    // simulate typical collection cursor fetch result
    return [{_id:"A"},{_id:"B"},{_id:"C"}];
  },
  myParam:function(){
    // here, this equals the current node item
    // so we _.extend our param with it
    return _.extend({paramName:"paramValue"},this);
  }
});

Template.child.helpers({
  someOtherHelper:function(){
    return "_id : "+this._id+" ; paramName : "+this.paramName;
  }
});

<template name="parent">
  {{#each nodes}}
    {{> child myParam}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="child">
  {{! this is going to output the same stuff}}
  <div>_id : {{_id}} ; paramName : {{paramName}}</div>
  <div>{{someOtherHelper}}</div>
</template>
```

Depending on what you're precisely trying to achieve, there might be a better approach but this one gets the job done at least.