# How to access global data inside a inner template on Meteor Iron-router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I´m using the Iron-router package and I´m having a problem to access global data in templates. I have a router.js wich defines:

router.js

```
var addMyData = function() {
    this.data = {myProp: 'value'};
}
Router.before(addMyData);
```

It works fine. If I need to use that inside a "each" handlebar, I can access the data using:

myTemplate.html

```
<template name='myTemplate>
     {{myProp}} //Works fine!
     {{#each something}}
        {{../myProp}} //Also works fine!
     {{/each}}
</template>
```

Great. But, when I need to use a inner template, all the data on the outter template just vanish. Example:

myTemplate.html

```
<template name='myTemplate>
    {{myProp}} //Works fine!
     {{#each something}}
        {{> myInnerTemplate}}
     {{/each}}
</template>

<template name='myInnerTemplate>
    {{../myProp}} //Not works!
</template>
```

The weirdest thing is that all the data from the outerTemplate are vanished.

Is that a bug, or there is another pratice to achieve the same goal?

Thank you.

Comment: You should read my answer to this question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413457/meteor-template-pass-a-parameter-into-each-sub-template-and-retrieve-it-in-the
I'm pretty sure you're encountering a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Handlebars helper I use in all my projects that is designed to address this issue, modified slightly from code at http://rockycode.com/blog/handlebars-loop-index/ (CoffeeScript):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper "iter", (context, options) ->
    fn = options.fn
    inverse = options.inverse
    ret = ""
    if context and context.length > 0
        i = 0
        j = context.length

        while i < j
            ret = ret + fn(_.extend({}, context[i],
                i: i
                context: context
                parent: @
                self: context[i]
            ))
            i++
    else
        ret = inverse(@)
    ret
```

Replace `{{#each}}` and `{{/each}}` in your templates with `{{#iter}}` and `{{/iter}}`, and you'll have new variables `parent`, `context` and `self`, as well as loop index `i`, available to you within your `iter` loop (and by extension, in the subtemplate).

So in your case, `{{../myProp}}` should be replaced by either `{{self.myProp}}` or `{{parent.myProp}}` (trial-and-error, one or the other should work). I doubt your issue is particular to Iron Router.