# meteor template compare/passing a variable

Tags: compare, meteor, parameter-passing

I want to do what should be a simple compare but I have been stuck for the longest time on this:

I have a template that calls a list template, each list is a new column.

For the first column, I do NOT want certain fields displayed. Each column has a variable {{type}}

I want to do either:

a) pass type to the list template so that list can render based on type equals something

or

b) do an compare on type before I call list (in an 'each' loop) - e.g. 
 {{#if $eq myVar "test"}}
  Show this text
 {{/if}}

Neither approach works.

This seems to be the simplest thing but I am scratching head and unable to find examples.

thank you

Max

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this does what you want to achieve, it would help if you post some of your HTML. But to do what you want in b) couldn't you do:

```
{{#if isEqual myVar "test"}}
  ...
{{/if}}
```

and

```
Template.example.helpers({
  isEqual: function(var1, var2) {
    return var1 === var2;
  }
});
```

Comment: Many thanks. I tried this using a session variable and the scope doesn't work for what I am trying to do (which is to conditionally render html in a template). As it turns out what I really need to do is pass a parm to a template from a parent e.g. similar to this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413457/meteor-template-pass-a-parameter-into-each-sub-template-and-retrieve-it-in-the) but I can't get it to work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier to use `collection.find({type: someType})` to just give your template what it should show.  Make someType a session variable and you are done.

This [sort example](http://mattfrear.com/2012/08/29/enhancing-the-meteor-leaderboard-sample/) shows this pattern.